# How do you return a row using MAX in a query in Google Sheets?

Tags: mysql, excel, google-sheets, max, formula

I'm trying to get a query to return a limited selection of cells based on the max value of a cell. I've tried using FILTER with zero luck.

My query is: =query(export!$A3:$AN,"Select G,C,AM,AL,AN,I group by MAX(I)",-1)

It should drop the data into the columns below with the max value for the "Reach" column.

ROW TITLE | Date | Post | Likes | Comments | Shares | Reach

[removed url]

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

=query(export!$A3:$AN,"Select G,C,AM,AL,AN,I order by I desc")